# Javascript - Search dynamic table and return entire row. Include all search terms

Tags: javascript

Still new to JS, but learning avidly.

**Background:** I wrote a big script, that does multiple API calls based on a single input (ID number), and renders a table filled with objects based on those promises. *Sample script below*.

**Problem:** I would like to add a search box with multiple inputs.
Then filter the table as follows:
 
First column: Search term. 
If found: show entire row. 
If not found: Display error code next to search term.

I found a similar question, but not what I'm looking for. Question: 21579635

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5LsHZ/1/) also seems close.

[Image of table I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQivu.png)

Current code (*Had to change a few details for a public post*):

```
var input = X2.input({
        controls: [{
                    name: 'IDs'
                },
                .then(function() {
                    return X2.describeArea();
                }).map(function(area, context) {
                        return _.map(IDs.split(/,|\s+|;|:/), function(IDs) {
                            return {
                                IDs: ids,
                                area: area.id,
                            }
                        });
                        .renderTable({
                                    title: "Account ID details",
                                    id: 'table',
                                    summaryFields: ['#', 'privateIpAddress', 'publicIpAddress', 'macAddress’]
                                    });
```

Comment: Your code is poor formatted and has syntactic errors. Please give us a nearly working example. :)

Comment: Hi Ole. I tweaked the format a bit. But your comment made me realise that the compiler I use is heavily customised, with a built-in underscore.js library. Which makes this question pretty difficult to ask and answer. I also can not share the compiler on a public form.

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question. There is a heavy load of dependencies in your snippet and still syntax errors. For example line 5 or line 11.

Comment: Thanks Ole, I expected as much. But thank you for trying nonetheless! :)  Will try and tweak the fiddle until it does what I need it to do, and then cry myself to sleep when I try and add it into my compiler and existing script.

Comment: No problem, good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Will have to sort it out myself, since there are too many dependencies and copyrighted intellectual properties for me to share a proper working example.